# HDFVR on Red5 - convert FLV to mp4 does not work

Tags: ffmpeg, red5

I'm trying to get [HDFVR](https://hdfvr.com) to convert FLV to MP4 with

```
$config['enableFFMPEGConverting'] = 1;
```

but unfortunately it doesn't work as it should. (even their demo on my localhost)

Sometimes it actually creates the mp4 (takes long and very bad quality though), but more or less [Red5](https://github.com/Red5) (I'm using 1.0.5 but tried 1.0.3 and 1.0.4 too) shows:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-6" java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not parse duration.
    at VideoRecorder.ProcessBuilderWrapper$1.run(ProcessBuilderWrapper.java:30)
```

I'm on localhost (os x) and ffmpeg executable was downloaded from [ffmpeg's site](https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html#build-mac) and put inside "streams/_definst_" folder as per [documentation](https://hdfvr.com/documentation#part19).

Also, hdfvr version when right clicking the video says: `HDFVR v2.0 build +499`.

If anyone has any tips about the above error I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Do you also have all involved codecs installed?

Involved codecs means codecs used when recording flash video (Sorenson H.263 or H264 and Speex or Nellymoser, depending on recorder implementation and settings) and for MP4 (H264 and AAC).

Check with ffmpeg -codecs . To filter use something like:

```
ffmpeg -codecs | grep -E 'h263|h264|speex|nellymoser|aac'
```

Should output ffmpeg info the codecs info similar to:

```
DEV.L. h263                 H.263 / H.263-1996, H.263+ / H.263-1998 / H.263 version 2
 D.V.L. h263i                Intel H.263
 DEV.L. h263p                H.263+ / H.263-1998 / H.263 version 2
 DEV.LS h264                 H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10 (encoders: libx264 libx264rgb )
 DEA.L. aac                  AAC (Advanced Audio Coding) (encoders: aac libfaac )
 D.A.L. aac_latm             AAC LATM (Advanced Audio Coding LATM syntax)
 DEA.L. nellymoser           Nellymoser Asao
 DEA.L. speex                Speex (decoders: libspeex ) (encoders: libspeex )
```

You can find instructions for installing different codecs at http://www.videochat-scripts.com/install-ffmpeg-mplayer-flvtool2-yamdi-x264-theora-mp3lame-vorbis-ogg-faac/ . Speex and Faac are usually missing for most installs. After installing new codec libraries you need to recompile ffmpeg with new codecs included.

To convert FLVs to higher quality mp4 you can also deploy a free solution like http://videosharevod.com/ that permits importing files from a server folder and converting these to mp4 in mobile and high quality settings.

Comment: It seems my codecs are fine.. Also, I must stress out that sometimes (rarely) flv to mp4 works just fine. But most of the time I get the error mentioned in my question :/ I'm lost, really.. And also, FLVs sometimes freeze at certain point and then continue after a few seconds. But sometimes they are very nice.

Comment: Try with Wowza Streaming Engine (free developer licenses available) as recording issue could be related to Red5.